# .Net or VB6 - Intercept spooler document and release after correct password

Tags: .net, spooler

I need to intercept the document to be printed and only release it to the printer after the user confirms his username and password.

I am pausing the printer, but it is not being efficient because Windows notifies and the user can take the printer out of the paused state.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Windows already knows who the user is and already checked the account against the printer object's permissions. Why not change the printer's permissions if you want to restrict access? You don't need to write any code (and with VB6, you can't do that anyway)

Comment: `and the user can take the printer out of the paused state.` that's no different than what you propose to do. Windows won't allow an unauthorized user to resume printing

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, are registered users on a web platform, I need to create a print management, with limits and costs per page. So I need to intercept the print and register the user to control the charges

Comment: Why not change the web application's code to ask for ... whatever ... before it prints then? Once again,  the web app uses authentication you already know who the user is. If it doesn't, it should. Allowing anonymous users to print is a bad idea

Comment: There are printing solutions like that. It is not feasible to register users on the machine, I will wait if someone has domain, because I do everything, I just can't hold a document in the spooler, I cancel, pause the printer, everything, I just can't make the spooler leave the document in "wait"